# Release signed Android App,Google Plus Login and Google Map not Working

Tags: android, google-maps, google-api, google-plus, google-play-services

1.I am using **Google plus login** and **Google map** in my android Application.

2.In while debugging the App from Android Studio to Real device(Mobile)Google plus login and Google Map **Works Fine.**(Everything Works fine)

**Problem:**

1.Build--> Generate Signed APK -from android Studio  ,i made Release apk its not able to login using **Google plus**.

2.Also **Google Map** is showing empty screen.

I tried to create **OAuth Client ID**, its Giving Error message from Google Developer Console

**Error Message:**
Duplicate fingerprint
The fingerprint you specified is already used by an Android OAuth2 client ID in this project or another project

[Link i reffered for Google plus Login](http://androidsrc.net/integrating-google-plus-sign-in-into-your-android-application/)

Please help me anyone how to resolve it.

**EDIT :1**

1.I tested **debug.apk** its worked perfectly Google plus login and map.

2.But not working in **release.apk**.help me how to solve it.

Comment: Your KeyHash is not sign. Add sign KeyHash

Comment: key hash is not sign means?, how to fix this issue

Comment: When you generate key hash give your signed apk path instead of debug apk and your release password

Comment: what is the need of Key hash for registering in Google developer Console for getting Google Api key and Oauth Client Id? just enough SHA1 and my application package name.

Comment: @sjd i generated Key Hash form cmd prompt , where i have to add the key hash in Google Developer Console.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have generate Sign keyHash like this .

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore %HOMEPATH%\.android\debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl
base64
```

**For Example Like this**

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_22\bin\keytool.exe" -exportcert -alias selvin -keystore c:\users\selvin\desktop\selvin.kp | C:\OpenSSL-Win32\bin\openssl sha1 -binary | C:\OpenSSL-Win32\bin\openssl base64
```

this is generate for CMD in your system add add this Hash key in your Google consol.

Comment: in google console where i have to add this Key Hash?

Comment: Go your console add select your app and go your Credentials and click your app Id and then show your keyhas.

Comment: then add your KeyHash

Comment: i created my Keyhash from cmd prompt.i went to my project Dashboard in google console. then where i can find add KeyHash COlumn?

Comment: click your App name and go your API Manager and then click Credentials and then click project key name..

Comment: yes ,in that Credential page is showing like, android key1,Creation date, Type,key. in this page where i have to My Key Hash generated from Cmd prompt

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95657/discussion-between-kumar-and-destro).

Comment: Sir,  I m facing same issue can u please tell me  solution If your problem  has been solved.

Answer (score 3):

If you haven't yet added the release SHA1 to the firebase console or developer console, please do it first and make sure you add the google-services.json downloaded from the console to the root of the project folder as given in the previous answers. If the issue still persists even after doing this, please add the following line to the proguard-rules.pro of your project.

`-keep class <package-name>.** {*;}`

**Note:** This method may increase the size of your app-release.apk, but the oauth login will work for sure. To reduce the size, be particular about the class that you specify in the proguard. For example,

`-keep class <package-name>.<class-name> {*;}`

The class name can be found if you know which class the proguard compresses such that the class is not executed. In this case, it is the login oauth that may have been prevented by the proguard from being executed. So, add that class along with any other pojo classes associated with the login in the proguard as shown below:

`-keep class <package-name>.<class-name> {*;}`

`-keep class <package-name>.<pojo-class> {*;}` (if any)

Add all the classes associated with the login as shown and you will be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is the SH1 hash, As much i understand people facing this issue, because they are using ***Debug SH1 Hash*** in the place of ***Release SH1 Hash*** ,both are different. Add your ***Release SH1 Hash*** in **OAuth 2.0 client IDs**. Hopefully it will help.

Answer (score 0):

```
keytool -exportcert -alias aliasname -keystore PathOfKeystore.jks | "C:\Users\Android\openssl\bin\openssl.exe" sha1 -binary | "C:\Users\Android\openssl\bin\openssl.exe" base64
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/206345) by showing _why_ this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.